# StackMob local core data storage

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, stackmob

I recently decided to make my move to StackMob (from Parse). I have managed to setup core data and i can read and write to StackMob datastore.

So far, StackMob offers a list of item to the user. If the user decides to user an item on my app, I want the item to be available offline, so he can use it without having to connect to stackmob.

I am thinking of creating a local Core Data and copying the items that the user select there. My first problem is if i could use the same object for both Core Data (stackmob and local). And if this is the right approach to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest sdk includes support for caching of core data. Details are In this [blog post](https://blog.stackmob.com/2013/01/ios-sdk-v1-2-0-released/).

> The caching system is off by default. To turn it on, simply set the SM_CACHE_ENABLED flag to YES in your App Delegate file, before you initialize a Core Data store. The flag is declared in SMCoreDataStore.h.

It also includes this code example for how to control the cache...

```
SMClient *client = [[SMClient alloc] initWithAPIVersion:@"0" publicKey:@"XXXX"];
SMCoreDataStore *coreDataStore = [client coreDataStoreWithManagedObjectModel:myModel];
[client.session.networkMonitor setNetworkStatusChangeBlockWithCachePolicyReturn:^SMCachePolicy(SMNetworkStatus status) {
        if (status == Reachable) {
            return SMCachePolicyTryNetworkElseCache;
        } else {
            return SMCachePolicyTryCacheOnly;
        }
}];
```

Comment: How is this parameter (SMNetworkStatus status) passed into the block? Or "SMNetworkStatus status" is a kind of global instance? Thanks.

Comment: By the sdk, not sure how. But you know stackmob has been shutdown after being purchased by PayPal?

Comment: Yes, I just knew it this week, Big brother choked it to death by May 11th 2014. Since nowhere to get its SDK tutorial downloaded, I searched StackOverflow and found your reply here.  I was still wondering if there is an iVAR "SMNetworkStatus status" inside "@interface SMNetworkReachability : AFHTTPClient" hidden in .m file, since this "SMNetworkReachability" class has a "- (SMNetworkStatus)currentNetworkStatus;" public method, which really looks like a Getter after facelift. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I am pretty sure it used the standard Apple reachability code... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I have to agree. Very likely, it was the "SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress" got the job done. Thanks David!